# Literary term for the stagehands on "The Masked Singer"

Tags: terminology, theater

On the American television singing contest "The Masked Singer", there is a cast of stagehands who play an essential role.  They are silent, anonymous, and wear identical dark suits and sunglasses.  The host simply refers to them as "men in black".

They serve three purposes in the context of the show:

1. **Stagehands** — holding props and retrieving clues
2. **Ushers** — helping the heavily-masked contestants to ascend and descend stairs and find their way backstage safely
3. **Dramatic stand-ins** — As the masked contestants recount pivotal moments in their lives, those moments are dramatized in dreamy little vignettes.  The masked contestant always plays themself, but the "men in black" act as stand-ins for any supporting characters.

It is the third role which is most intriguing.  For example, when the Bee contestant (Gladys Knight) recalled her upbringing in Georgia, the "men in black" acted as stand-ins for the family members and other children at her birthday party.  Obviously, it is absurd to have men in suits playing her grandmother, her mother, and children with little party hats on their heads, but we the audience understood that they were meant as placeholders for people who cannot be depicted.

I know this must be a recurring device in the history of theater, but the only similar thing I can identify are the Gravediggers/Clowns in "Hamlet".  **Is there a more general or formal theatrical term to describe such multifunctional stagehands/stand-ins?**

Comment: [Kuroko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuroko)